# Filter androidDependencies by debug or release

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My app's dependencies are as simple as possible. I only `implement` support library. Now I want to know dependencies in my app.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

`./gradlew -q :app:androidDependencies` can help me show app's dependencies. However the result is a little long.

```
debug
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0@jar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0@aar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0@jar
\--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0@jar

debugRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0@jar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0@aar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0@jar
\--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0@jar

debugAndroidTest
debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0@jar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0@aar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0@jar
\--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0@jar

debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging

debugUnitTest
debugUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0@jar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0@aar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0@jar
\--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0@jar
```

As you see, there are all `productFlavors` such as `debugCompileClasspath` , `debugRuntimeClasspath` and so on. Can I add filter to only show such as `debugCompileClasspath` item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From help command `./gradlew help --task :app:androidDependencies`, I do not have found any option so maybe task `:app:androidDependencies` can not do well.

```
> Task :help
Detailed task information for :app:androidDependencies

Path
     :app:androidDependencies

Type
     DependencyReportTask (com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DependencyReportTask)

Description
     Displays the Android dependencies of the project.

Group
     Android
```

From `./gradlew tasks`, there is another similar task called `app:dependencies`. And it has an option.

```
> Task :help
Detailed task information for app:dependencies

Path
     :app:dependencies

Type
     DependencyReportTask (org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.DependencyReportTask)

Options
     --configuration     The configuration to generate the report for.

Description
     Displays all dependencies declared in project ':app'.

Group
     help
```

Then command `./gradlew -q app:dependencies --configuration debugCompileClasspath` save my eyes.